# Android SQL Lite int value stored as string shows extra characters when retrieved

Tags: java, string, mongodb, sqlite, go

I have phone numbers stored in a MongoDB database as Double (mistakenly). So numbers appear somewhat like this in the database -

```
180010000001.0
```

I fetch this through a golang backend and the response it gives is surprisingly this -

```
{
"phoneNumber": 180010000001
}
```

I am not passing this data through any structs, its just a simple `mgo` query

```
MgoSession.DB(Dbname).C(collectionName).Find(query).All(&result)
```

which returns an array of interfaces `[]interface{}`

Now I consume this web service on my Android app and store these values internally in SQL Lite for using throughout the app, like this -

```
phoneNumber TEXT
```

Then I store it like this,

```
contentValues.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
```

And fetch it like this -

```
cursor.getColumnIndex("phoneNumber")
```

and assign it to a variable I have declared as `String`

Now when I print this out, it shows -

```
1.80010000001E11
```

Where did this transition happen?!

Comment: Something in the chain is configured to treat numeric strings as floating point numbers. Does golang do that?

Comment: Golang's response surprisingly 'looks' like an integer but being in JSON, I'm assuming it can be fetched in Java as both an integer and a string.
I'm fetching it using JSONObject.getString() method..

Comment: Assuming the column in the DB is a string, then somewhere in the chain between the DB and your code it was converted to floating point, which is not good.  You'll have to figure out where.

Comment: I know! I need to try more and find out where this confusion happened. Thank you for point out the direction to look in!

Comment: Actually, your title says _"Android SQL Lite int value..."_ are you _sure_ it's stored in the DB as a string?

Comment: Not really sure because the database scheme defines the field as 'TEXT'.

Comment: When you `.put()` the float appears to be stringified, via: `String.valueOf(180010000001.0)` - which encodes to scientific notation; as does Go: https://play.golang.org/p/4XAQYgX5aT

Comment: Thank you for the response @MartinGallagher !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSON text:

```
{
"phoneNumber": 180010000001
}
```

Defines a JSON object with a property `"phoneNumber"` whose value is a [JSON number](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm): `180010000001`. Note: the value is not a JSON string as if it would be, it would be in quotes and would look like this:

```
{"phoneNumber": "180010000001"}
```

Back to the original: it's a JSON number, so when the JSON text is parsed and converted back to either a Java or a Go value, it will be a floating point number. And when a floating point number is printed, often (when the number is too "big" or too "small") the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is used which in your case is:

```
180010000001 = 1.80010000001E11
```

If you want to avoid this (you should), you must declare your phone number to be either a `long` type (in Java) or `uint64` (in Go), or preferaly simply declare it to be of `string` type, so no "mysterious" formatting for rounding errors will come up.

If you already have it saved in MongoDB as a double, either load all and re-save them as `string` (preferable), or if you don't want to do that, convert it to `string` before sending it to your clients.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I did the last thing - saved all my values as strings.